# Sort 2 dimensional List based on first indexvalue

Tags: c#, arrays, list, sorting

I have added following values in to my 2D List (List of Lists). It contains weight of fruits followed by their names. Can you please tell me how can I sort this 2D array base on the first index value of weight?

```
List<List<String>> matrix = new List<List<String>>();
matrix.Add(new List<String>()); //Adds new sub List
matrix[0].Add("3.256"); 
matrix[0].Add("Apple");       

matrix.Add(new List<String>());
matrix[1].Add("1.236"); 
matrix[1].Add("Orange");           

matrix.Add(new List<String>());
matrix[2].Add("1.238"); 
matrix[2].Add("Banana");

matrix.Add(new List<String>());
matrix[2].Add("2.658"); //updated This should be matrix[3] instead of 2
matrix[2].Add("Apple");
....
...
..

Console.WriteLine(matrix[0][0]);//This prints out the value 3.256. after sorting it should print out 1.236
```

I am new to C# and please show me with an example if this is possible

Comment: Rather than using a 2D ArrayList, you should create a custom class and then use a list of objects from that class.

Comment: Thanks for all of your comments and answers. They were all very helpful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simple answer:

```
matrix.OrderBy( l => l[0]);
```

Okay, this is a *really* bad design, first because the string compare is *not* going to give you the same order a `double` compare would. Easy enough to fix:

```
matrix.OrderBy( l => double.Parse(l[0]));
```

Except now it will throw an exception if you typed a number incorrectly (and can't be parsed into a double). What you *really* want to do is create a "Fruit" object:

```
class Fruit
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double Weight { get; set; }
}
```

And hold a `List<Fruit>`. Now you can write:

```
matrix.OrderBy(f => f.Weight);
```

With no problems with exceptions, since you will get a compile time error if you wrote it wrong.

**OrderBy returns an IEnumerable, so make sure you utilize the return value instead of `matrix` when printing**

Comment: @BradleyDotNET Can you please explain more about what you mean by List<Fruit>. is that mean I should rename my arraylist as `List<List<Fruit>> matrix = new List<List<Fruit>>();` after creating a class called Fruit as you described above

Comment: @DP. No, a single `List<Fruit>` will contain your data just fine. The "2D" is not needed because you have encapsulated your related data into an object ("Fruit" in this case).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to redesign your program and create a class which holds the related data. This will correspond to a "row" in your current 2D list. Now you can create an list of objects from this class and define a custom ordering for sorting.

Note that this has the added benefit that you can treat numeric data as such rather than treating all data as Strings.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET Thanks for the suggestion. I'm a C# noob coming from Java, so LINQ extensions are still quite foreign to me.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET I probably should have said `List`. Need to go study the C# data structure object hierarchies.